# magento 2 How to add custom content under the buy button for a specific product

Tags: static-block, widget

I want to add some custom content under the shopping button on the product page of the specified category. I have used the block and widget functions to create it, but the display position is not what I want. How to achieve it?

[image]

Comment: you can call custom phtml file after add to cart button and put your content in phtml. with tour condition

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a module to show a **custom content** on the **product page** of **specified category**. Check below files

> app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Module.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Module extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context  $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/custom_content.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Vendor\Module\Block\Module
 */
?>
<div class="custom-content">
    <!-- Your category condition here -->
    <?php if($block->getCurrentCategory()->getId() == 12): ?>
        <p>Your Custom content here</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Module" name="custom.content.on.product" template="Vendor_Module::custom_content.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This will add the content under the Add to cart buttons.

Hope this will help you.